How to run pynput.keyboard.listener in a class inherited from customtinker.Ctk?
I have a GUI written in Customtkinter, I want to make it possible to activate a script by pressing F6 in addition to clicking a button in the GUI itself. The way I wrote doesn't work, the console opens, but the GUI itself doesn't.
import customtkinter
from PIL import Image
import ctypes
from pynput import keyboard

#icon on taskbar
myappid = 'mycompany.myproduct.subproduct.version' # arbitrary string
ctypes.windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)


#main script
class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        def display_resolution_menu_callback(choiced_resolution):
            print("optionmenu dropdown clicked:", choiced_resolution, stamina_farm.get())
        
        def start_stop_button_callback():
            if self.start_stop_button.cget("text") == "Start (F6)":
                self.start_stop_button.configure(text="Stop (F6)", fg_color="#C20000", hover_color="#8B0000")
                print("started")
            else:
                self.start_stop_button.configure(text="Start (F6)", fg_color="green", hover_color="#006A00")
                print("stopped!")
        
        def on_release(key):
            if key == keyboard.Key.f6:
                start_stop_button_callback()
        
        with keyboard.Listener(on_release=on_release) as listener:
            listener.join()
        

        #head
        self.title("Gym League Bot")
        self.geometry("400x500")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.iconbitmap("C:/Users/Filimonick/Desktop/BotCreatingTools/gym.ico")

        #logo
        self.logo = customtkinter.CTkImage(dark_image=Image.open("C:/Users/Filimonick/Desktop/BotCreatingTools/logo.png"), size=(365, 120))
        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self, text="", image=self.logo)
        self.logo_label.place(x=18, y=20)

        #display resolution menu
        self.display_resolution_menu_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=self, width=180, height=60)
        self.display_resolution_menu_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.display_resolution_menu_frame, text="Display resolution", fg_color="#4A0A6F", corner_radius=6, width=180, font=("Outfit Bold", 20))
        self.display_resolution_menu_frame.place(x=15, y=150)
        self.display_resolution_menu_label.place(x=0, y=0)
        self.display_resolution_menu = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(master=self.display_resolution_menu_frame, values=["1920x1080", "2560x1080"],
                                                                   command=display_resolution_menu_callback, fg_color="#4A0A6F", corner_radius=6, width=180, font=("Outfit Bold", 20), button_color="#430865")
        self.display_resolution_menu.place(x=0, y=30)
        
        #stamina farm switcher
        stamina_farm = customtkinter.BooleanVar(value=False)
        self.stamina_farm_switch = customtkinter.CTkSwitch(master=self, text="Stamina Farm", progress_color="#4A0A6F", font=("Outfit Bold", 20), variable=stamina_farm)
        self.stamina_farm_switch.place(x=210, y=150)
    
        #start stop button
        self.start_stop_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self, text="Start (F6)", width=180, fg_color="green", hover_color="#006A00", command=start_stop_button_callback)
        self.start_stop_button.place(x=210, y=180)

app = App()
app.mainloop()

I looked for solutions on stackoverflow, but I couldn't apply them, they were crashing all the code

There's no need for pynput. Just use the regular customtkinter keyboard detection, which means doing: self.bind("<Key>", callback_function). That is, unless you need pynput for a specific reason.
